# What is the difference between acetate sheets and baking paper when making chocolate deco?

Tags: cake, chocolate, culinary-uses, melting-chocolate

I would like to make chocolate decorations with melted chocolate. After searching on the web, however, I am not quite sure I could find acetate sheets. But I can find baking paper.

Would there be any substitute, like baking paper, parchment paper? What is the difference between them?

I want to make melted-chocolate decorations like those around this cake:

[image: Cake decorated with chocolate swirls]

Comment: "What is the difference between them?" ... "Acetate sheet" sounds like cellophane to me...

Comment: I am not quite sure what it is called, maybe acetate plastic, or whatever kinda sheet of plastic that can hold the chocolate... and be safe and not sticky... :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acetate sheets posses a firm and rigid shape, with a glossy coating that assists the removal of decorations such as chocolate decoration. It also can be shaped without being indented at any point which baking parchment most frequently fails to do.

Baking parchment is very agile, this fails to support decorations as a mould, and would consequently lead to breakage of the decoration should the parchment not retain a flat edge. It could also bend in frequent points, misshaping the chocolate. This is what makes it suited towards cakes, as as it can be ripped off.

I would therefore conclude that it would be most suitable for you to use acetate sheets.

Answer (score 2):

I think generally acetate sheets are used for this kind of thing because they're a bit stiffer than baking paper. They're also shinier, and as a general rule, the shinier the surface that you put the chocolate on, the shinier the chocolate will be. You could use baking paper but the result is not going to be as good.

Like other people said, acetate is clear plastic. You can often get it from arts and crafts stores if there isn't a fancy confectioner place you go for supplies. It's probably easiest to buy it online though, if you don't mind waiting. Make sure you search for food grade acetate. E.g.: http://www.countrykitchensa.com/shop/essentials/acetate-sheets-12-x-18/40/582/617/629475/

Comment: There are good reasons to use acetate sheets, the flexibility and releaseability among them. Although, I question the idea that the shinier the surface, the shinier the chocolate.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the disposable cutting sheets they sell at dollar tree and other stores are the same thing or wood work. They are ment to cut up fruits and vegetables on without  cutting the counter. I'm assuming they are safe for food.it might be worth looking into. I think the are sold at most grocery stores too just more money.

Comment: They are not the same thing (an acetate sheet is thinner and wouldn't protect the counter very much from chopping), although they are safe for food.